Whats the difference between Seachem prime and AmGuard? Can I use Prime instead of AmGuard?
My aquarium has higher Amonia right now and I am debating if I can utilize Prime or must purchase a specific Amonia reducer.
Is AmGuard a just more concentrated Prime? Can I utilize Prime to bring my Amonia back to safe levels?
If I use Prime, should I add more of it?
Many of the Local Fish Shops in my area do not have AmGuard in stock currently.
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

for how long did you cycle your tank before adding fish and plants,you can take a look here https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm on how to cycle a tank.

Leaving as just a comment as it's anecdotal, but when I had ammonia spikes with my tanks, my now-closed LFS told me to use Prime as part of the management. "Just dump it in, you can't overdose. Glug glug!"
